# How to convert duration column from 1 hr. 17 min to 77 min in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, data-cleaning, dataframe

I am trying to convert all the hr., min, and sec into just mins. For example, 1 hr. 17 min to 77 min, and 34 sec to 0.56 min, not 0.34 min.

[image]

So I have used this code:

```
merged['duration'] = merged['duration'].str.replace(" hr.", '*60').str.replace(' ','+').str.replace(' min','*1').str.replace(' ','+').str.replace(' sec','*0.01').apply(eval)
```

From: [How to Convert a Pandas Column having duration details in string format (ex:1hr 50m) into a integer column with value in minutes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46909/how-to-convert-a-pandas-column-having-duration-details-in-string-format-ex1hr)

But it gives me this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

I am not sure how to go about it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the spaces with a `+` character before replacing `` and . Therefore the minutes and seconds do not get replaced, which in turn cannot be evaluated using `eval`. Reordering the different operations should solve the error:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].str.replace(" hr.", '*60').str.replace(' min','*1').str.replace(' sec','*0.01').str.replace(' ','+').apply(eval)
```

You are mentioning that you want 34 seconds converted to 0.34, but if you want everything in minutes this does not make sense since 34 seconds is 34/60=0.56 seconds. If you also want to change this the following should work:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].str.replace(" hr.", '*60').str.replace(' min','*1').str.replace(' sec','*(1/60)').str.replace(' ','+').apply(eval)
```